# Hazelcast Queue - load balancing

Tags: hazelcast

I am planning to introduce Hazelcast IQueue as a distributed task queue for the project I am working on.
There are multiple stateless services will consume tasks from such queue, a question come to my mind is ---- load balancing issue.
How can I guarantee the load is relative balanced, while those stateless services consume tasks from the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Queues provide fairness.

Assuming the code is a loop of `IQueue.take()` and process, then if `take()` requests come from instance A, instance B, instance A and instance A again, then instance A gets 3 messages and B gets 1.

If this is due to the messages requiring different amounts of time to process, then with sufficient messages this should even out. If instance 1 is on faster hardware than instance 2 then it won't.

If you need the instances to follow a round-robin approach then you'd need to implement this yourself.

You could use something like `IAtomicLong` to record whose turn is next. All processing stops if the instance whose turn is next goes offline, which might not be what you want. The [CP Subsystem](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/cp-subsystem/cp-subsystem) provides a fuller featured approach that you can use for scheduling.